# Qt (linux) - Incompatible version of OpenSSL (built with OpenSSL 1.x, runtime version is >= 3.x)

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I built a qt c++ application on a Linux system which uses network requests as part of its functionality, and on the system which it was built on it works alright, after I deployed it (using cqtdeployer), and ran the application on a different Linux computer, the GUI opens up and everything, but when it tries to perform HTTP requests it logs the following error to the console:

> qt.tlsbackend.ossl: Incompatible version of OpenSSL (built with OpenSSL 1.x, runtime version is >= 3.x)

My question is - can Qt be built with modern OpenSSL versions, or do I have to manually install OpenSSL1.x on the computer which tries to run the program? Maybe I can just provide a bunch of libraries to the deployment folder?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you expect version 1.x and version 3.x of a library to be compatible?

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL is generally binary incompatible between major versions, especially with version 3, which is a major API change.

Perhaps it will be a good investment of time for you to take this opportunity to learn how to use your Linux distribution's package manager, (rpm/dnf on Fedora-based Linux distributions, and dpkg/apt on Debian-derived distributions) which exists precisely to solve these kinds of problems.

Most major Linux distributions still include an additional compatibility package for code that's built with OpenSSL 1. If you use your Linux distribution's package manager and prepared an appropriate package, the compatibility package would've gotten installed, automatically, by the package manager together with your package. That's what the package manager is for.

It's also a fair chance that the version of Qt is different too, and there's also a high chance of an incompatibility between your code that's compiled for one version of Qt and the different version that's installed on the computer in question, even though it seemingly runs. If you used the package manager it would've figured it out too, and alerted you.